# MainActivity cannot find gridView

Tags: android, gridview

MainActivity is not recognizing the gridview in my xml file

This is the mainActivity onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContext = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mMovieFragment = new MovieFragment();
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, mMovieFragment)
                .commit();
    }
    if(this == null){
        Log.v(null, "THIS is empty");
    }
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    if(gridView == null){
        Log.v(null, "GridView is empty");
    }
    /*gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, mMovieFragment.getArrayImages()));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });*/
}
```

Then I have 2 xml files, activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity"
     tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

And fragment_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$MovieFragment">

</GridView>
```

**gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridview) is null**

MovieFragment.java:

```
public class MovieFragment extends Fragment{

public ArrayAdapter<String> mMovieAdapter;
public String[] mArrayImages;

public MovieFragment(){
    mArrayImages = new String[20];
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    new FetchMoviesTask().execute("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=37068e0a72b2cc1751b4246899923ba7");

}

public String[] getArrayImages() {
    return mArrayImages;
}

public class FetchMoviesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchMoviesTask.class.getSimpleName();

    private Void getMovieImagesFromJson(String movieJSONstr) throws JSONException {

        final String OWM_RESULTS = "results";
        final String OWM_POSTERPATH = "poster_path";

        JSONObject movieJson = new JSONObject(movieJSONstr);
        JSONArray movieArray = movieJson.getJSONArray(OWM_RESULTS);

        Log.v("SIZE MOVIE ARRAY: ", Integer.toString(movieArray.length()));

        for(int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject movieObj = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);
            mArrayImages[i] = movieObj.getString(OWM_POSTERPATH);
            Log.v("String "+i+":", mArrayImages[i]);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        String movieJSONstr = null;

        try{
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if(inputStream == null){
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if(buffer.length() == 0){
                movieJSONstr = null;
            }
            movieJSONstr = buffer.toString();
            Log.v("URLoutput: ", movieJSONstr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);

            return null;
        } finally{
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("MovieFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

        try{
            return getMovieImagesFromJson(movieJSONstr);
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should be doing that in your Movie fragment since your gridview is in the fragment, not the main activity. the activity only contains a container for the fragment.

Comment: I know but it doesnt recognize the findViewById method

Comment: post your fragment code.

Comment: I added the moviefragment class

Comment: Inflate your fragment_main.xml in the onCreateView and use the view returned for your findViewById calls. Had you tried that?

Comment: Done, I think its good, although images are not still not appearing, but that's another problem... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `findViewById` calls, you need to inflate your fragments xml and use the view returned to "find" your views.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        GridView grid = rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        new FetchMoviesTask().execute("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=37068e0a72b2cc1751b4246899923ba7");

    }
```

You can also easily set your grid adapter in your AsyncTasks `onPostExecute` by making your `doInBackground` return your string array

```
public class FetchMoviesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

 @Override
 protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
    //get your string array.
     //mArrayImages = assign the value 

      return mArrayImages;
     }
@Override
protected onPostExecute(String[] strings) {
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), strings);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should get gridview reference in MovieFragment's onCreateView method

Comment: and how do I do that?

Comment: just like activity lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

problem lies in fragment adding.

from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit()

commit is not performed immediatly, it will be done later

at the time you look for your grid, the fragment is not yet attached, and so, grid not not exist at this moment

you have to wait that fragment is really attached before retrieving your view

Comment: how do I do that because I want to populate the gridview as soon as the application starts

Comment: try in 'onResume', it may work. another solution would be to "post" a runnable that will find the gridview. it will be executed just after the commit